# system of non-homogeneous advection equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, partial-derivative, maple

I would like to solve this system 
\begin{equation}
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{lll}
u_t+b_1 u_x=(r+l_1)u-l_1v,\\
v_t+b_2 v_x=(r+l_2)v-l_2u,\\
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}

First , I would like to try with Maple to solve

> sys := [diff(u(x,t),t)+b1*diff(u(x,t),x)=(r+l1)*u(x,t)-l1*v(x,t),
>           diff(v(x,t),t)+b2*diff(v(x,t),x)=(r+l2)*v(x,t)-l2*u(x,t)];
>
> sol:=pdsolve(sys,[u,v]) assuming b1>b2;

The output looks like this :

[image]

I read some note about advection systems. Most of the papers I read deal with
system of homogeneous advection equations. No thing seems relates to non-homogeneous system of advection equations. My  questions are :

1) is there a simple way to find the close form solution $(u,v)$ of the above system ?

2) Under what conditions imposed on $b_1,b_2,r, l_1,l_2$, the system will admit an unique solution ?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the original PDE system and conditions? Is it just the advection equation $u_{t} + bu_{x} = c_{1}u - c_{2} v$? It can be difficult to read code sometimes.

Comment: Thanks ! please let me edit it

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the Maple output. You can't expect a simple answer with all the parameters $r,l_1,l_2,b_1,b_2$ being arbitrary. The $C_1$, $C_2$ and $c_1$ are arbitrary constants which arise from the lack of an intial condition. To see a more compact form of the solution (which $\mathbf{is}$ closed form), try specifying $r,l_1,l_2,b_1,b_2$ and then use: "simplify(expand(sol));". The $c_1$ constant comes from the integrating factor and can be done with only if you have some initial conditions.

Comment: can I assume $_c_1=0$ here ?

Comment: @DaveNguyen: Yes.